# Why did my password-protected MacBook unlock immediately after waking?

Tags: password, unlock

I have a 2015 MacBook Pro that is set up to require password to unlock immediately after sleep or screensaver begins. Well, I opened it up this morning after having it closed all night and it immediately showed my desktop, no password prompt shown. This seems like a serious security problem if it is just a random bug, so is there any chance I did something on my end to cause this? Thanks.

Comment: What are the settings at System Preferences > Users & Groups > (you) > Login Items? If you now sleep and then wake the MacBook, does it log you in again without action by you? What happens if you restart the MacBook?

Comment: Do you have an Apple Watch? If so, in **Security & Privacy** > **General** tab, is the "**Use your Apple Watch to unlock apps and your Mac**" selected?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Another explanation would be that your Mac wasn't in sleep mode at all. What is the output of `pmset -g log | grep -E 'Wake from|Entering Sleep' | tail -n 20` (this command displays the most recent 20 instances of sleep/wake activity - you may need to increase the number to show the relevant date)?